# How do I get HTTP Request body content in Laravel?

Tags: php, xml, laravel, phpunit

I am making an API with `Laravel 5` and I'm testing it with `PHPUnit`. I need to test legacy functionality for compatibility, which is an XML POST. As of right now, my first test looks like:

```
public function testPostMessages()
{
    $response = $this->call('POST', 'xml');

    $this->assertEquals(200, $response->getStatusCode());
}
```

This is passing just fine. Next on my list is actually sending the XML data with the POST. So for my second test, I have:

```
public function testPostMessagesContent()
{
    $response = $this->call('POST', 'xml');

    $this->assertTrue(is_valid_xml($response->getContent()));
}
```

This test fails. However, I am not sending my XML data. **How do I send my XML?**
Now, after that I need to add in the functionality to get the content from the request. I know there is a `Request` object that I can interact with but I don't exactly know which method to call on it. **How do I get my XML from inside my controller?**

---

#### Update #1

I was able to get some results in the meantime. My current test looks like this:

```
public function testPostMessagesContent()
{
    $response = $this->call('POST', 'xml', array('key' => 'value'), array(), array(), array('content' => 'content'));
    $this->assertContains('~', $response->getContent());
}
```

I only have the tilde there because I know it won't match so that I can see the whole response. In `XmlController.php` I have:

```
class XmlController extends Controller {
public function index(Request $request)
{
    return $request;
    }
}
```

My output from `PHPUnit` is as follows:

```
1) XmlTest::testPostMessagesContent
Failed asserting that 'POST xml HTTP/1.1
Accept:          text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Charset:  ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Content-Type:    application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host:            localhost
User-Agent:      Symfony/2.X
' contains "~".
```

Where are my parameters and my content? I feel like I am simply just using `call()` incorrectly.

---

#### Update #2

I updated my controller to use `Request:all()` like so:

```
class XmlController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
   {
        $content = Request::all();
        return $content;
    }
}
```

This returned my key-value pair, but not the content.

```
1) XmlTest::testPostMessagesContent
Failed asserting that '{"key":"value"}' contains "~".
```

Key-value pairs are good; it's progress. However, what I really need is the content since I'll be receiving that data in the content portion of the request. If I use `Request::getContent()` I get back a blank string. Here's my call in the test:

```
$response = $this->call('POST', 'xml', array('key' => 'value'), array(), array(), array('content' => 'content'));
```

Here's my test results:

```
1) XmlTest::testPostMessagesContent
Failed asserting that '' contains "~".
```

---

#### Update #3

I am not able to get the content body of an HTTP Request at all. Since XML wasn't working, I moved forward with the REST part of my API, which uses JSON. Here's one of my tests:

```
public function testPostMessagesContent()
{
    $response = $this->call('POST', 'messages', ['content' => 'content']);

    $this->assertEquals('saved!', $response->getContent());
}
```

This test passes. If I use curl, I get a successful call as well:

```
curl -X POST -d "content=my_new_content" "http://localhost:8000/messages"
```

This returns `'saved!'` That's awesome, but if I try to use curl in a standalone PHP script (to simulate a client), this is what is returned:

```
Array ( [url] => http://localhost:8000/messages [content_type] => text/html; charset=UTF-8 [http_code] => 302 [header_size] => 603 [request_size] => 118 [filetime] => -1 [ssl_verify_result] => 0 [redirect_count] => 0 [total_time] => 0.063977 [namelookup_time] => 0.000738 [connect_time] => 0.000866 [pretransfer_time] => 0.000943 [size_upload] => 12 [size_download] => 328 [speed_download] => 5126 [speed_upload] => 187 [download_content_length] => -1 [upload_content_length] => 12 [starttransfer_time] => 0.057606 [redirect_time] => 0 [certinfo] => Array ( ) [primary_ip] => ::1 [primary_port] => 8000 [local_ip] => ::1 [local_port] => 63248 [redirect_url] => http://localhost:8000 [request_header] => POST /messages HTTP/1.1 Host: localhost:8000 Accept: */* Content-type: text/xml Content-length: 12 ) Redirecting to http://localhost:8000.
```

This is my curl command adding the POST fields:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'content=test');
```

It seems to me that POSTFIELDS is getting added to the body of the request. In this case, I still have the same problem. I am not able to get body content of my HTTP headers. After commenting out my validation, I get:

```
Array ( [url] => http://localhost:8000/messages [content_type] => text/html; charset=UTF-8 [http_code] => 200 [header_size] => 565 [request_size] => 118 [filetime] => -1 [ssl_verify_result] => 0 [redirect_count] => 0 [total_time] => 0.070225 [namelookup_time] => 0.000867 [connect_time] => 0.00099 [pretransfer_time] => 0.001141 [size_upload] => 12 [size_download] => 6 [speed_download] => 85 [speed_upload] => 170 [download_content_length] => -1 [upload_content_length] => 12 [starttransfer_time] => 0.065204 [redirect_time] => 0 [certinfo] => Array ( ) [primary_ip] => ::1 [primary_port] => 8000 [local_ip] => ::1 [local_port] => 63257 [redirect_url] => [request_header] => POST /messages HTTP/1.1 Host: localhost:8000 Accept: */* Content-type: text/xml Content-length: 12 ) saved!
```

So I have my `'saved!'` message. Great! But, in my database now I have a blank row. Not great. It is still not seeing the body content, just the headers.

---

#### Answer Criteria

I'm looking for the answers to these questions:

1. Why can't I get the body content of my request?
2. How do I get the body content of my request?

Answer (score 198, accepted):

Inside controller inject Request object. So if you want to access request body inside controller method 'foo' do the following:

```php
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

    public function foo(Request $request){
        $bodyContent = $request->getContent();
    }
```

Comment: The full namespace for the class is `Illuminate\Http\Request`

Comment: Would content be binary-equal to "```$payload = @file_get_contents('php://input');```"?

Answer (score 8):

For those who are still getting blank response with `$request->getContent()`, you can use:

`$request->all()`

e.g:

```
public function foo(Request $request){
   $bodyContent = $request->all();
}
```

Comment: I don't believe this works. I am getting an [] after $request->all().

Comment: This doesn't work.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think you want the data from your **Request**, I think you want the data from your **Response**.  The two are different.  Also you should build your response correctly in your controller.

Looking at the class in edit #2, I would make it look like this:

```
class XmlController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $content = Request::all();
        return Response::json($content);
    }
}
```

Once you've gotten that far you should check the content of your response in your test case (use print_r if necessary), you should see the data inside.

More information on Laravel responses here:

http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/responses

Comment: What I was thinking... I didn't know that requests could have a body, actually they can, if it's a POST or PUT request...

Answer (score 4):

You can pass *data* as the third argument to `call()`. Or, depending on your API, it's possible you may want to use the sixth parameter.

From the [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/testing#calling-routes-from-tests):

```
$this->call($method, $uri, $parameters, $files, $server, $content);
```

Comment: I am passing data like this in my updated test. I think the sixth parameter is what I should be using for my legacy functionality tests. But I am still not receiving any data from the request: just the headers.

Comment: thanks a lot for sharing this. This information is available on the Laravel 4.2 docs, but is conspicuously absent in the most recent docs (5.5) . What gives Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one..

```
$userinput = request()->getContent();
  $toArray = explode('&', $userinput);
  foreach ($toArray as $toArr) {
    $arr1[] = explode('=', $toArr);
    $arr2 = [];
    foreach ($arr1 as $a1 ) {
      $arr2[$a1[0]] = $a1[1];
    }
  };

  return $arr2;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).