# php error fopen() "Filename cannot be empty at"

Tags: php, laravel

I am doing a
`curl -d @data.csv myserver.com` to POST Data to my linux server. Using laravel my routes will route the POST request to a function inside my Controller.php:

```
    public function endpoint(Request $request)
    {
        $handle = $request->file('data.csv');
        $use = fopen($request->file('data.csv'), "r");
    }
```

Now the errorlog returns: `[2021-06-24 15:44:55] production.ERROR: fopen(): Filename cannot be empty {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): fopen()` --> so the expected data.csv ist not arriving, the request seems to be empty. Of course, I googled the issue first. All answers online say this is due to wrong permissions on the folder where the uploaded file is temporarily stored, but where is that? Doing a
`$temp_file = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'Tux'); echo $temp_file;`  echos `/tmp/TuxWk8llX`  which leads me to belive the default tmp directory is /tmp/. My php.ini says also that /tmp/ is this upload directory (see below). But doing an `ls`on /tmp/ shows it has all permissions: `drwxrwxrwt.   1 root root    57 Jun 24 13:28 tmp`
So why is the request not coming through, any ideas? Thanks in advance, am really confused about by this! :)
PS: Might this `; sys_temp_dir = "/tmp"` in the php.ini cause the problem?

```
**php.ini config file**
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; File Uploads ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; Whether to allow HTTP file uploads.
; http://php.net/file-uploads
file_uploads = On

; Temporary directory for HTTP uploaded files (will use system default if not
; specified).
; http://php.net/upload-tmp-dir
upload_tmp_dir = /tmp

; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
; http://php.net/upload-max-filesize
upload_max_filesize = 200M

; Maximum number of files that can be uploaded via a single request
max_file_uploads = 20

; Directory where the temporary files should be placed.
; Defaults to the system default (see sys_get_temp_dir)
; sys_temp_dir = "/tmp"
```

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#file-paths-extensions

Comment: Ok, can you explain how this can be put to use?
```public function endpoint(Request $request)
    {
        $path = $request->path();     
        \Log::info($path);
    }```
gives me this log: `[2021-06-24 16:21:07] production.INFO: /` . If that is true, than the default directory to store data is / where I would doubt the application has sufficient permissions to store data, right?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31669672/2310830

Comment: ok so ```public function endpoint(Request $request)
    {
$info = $request->getContent();
\Log::info($info);
    }``` give the following log: `[2021-06-24 16:29:29] production.INFO:   ` so it seems there is just nothing there.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe read the documentation @ https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#retrieving-uploaded-files

`$request->file('data.csv')` will contain an object of a temp file IF the POST field is named `data.csv`.

Comment: hi, ok so the problem is more how to name the post field correctly? I am using curl -F `'name=data.csv' myserver.com` to post the data. Is that correct?

Comment: Suggets you dump the content of the request object to see whats actuall there

Comment: ok thanks for the suggestion to read documentioan. I found the solution doing it:
Adding ``use Illuminate\Http\Request;`` to the routes did the trick for me. Thank you for your help. lel!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:
Adding `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` to the routes did the trick for me. Thank you for your help.